# Can't clone over git without providing username

Tags: git

usually I do ``` git clone myusername@bitbucket...``
I have cleaned out ```~/.ssh`
I have created a new key pair according to [this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Generating-Your-SSH-Public-Key)

I want to be able to clone using just `git@bitbucket...`
But this always gives me an error, eventhough I have a public key (and I have added the public key to bitbucket):

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'xxx.xxx.xxx.x' to the list of known hosts.
repository access denied.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.



git config --list

credential.helper=osxkeychain
user.email=xyz@gmail.com
user.name=XX XX
core.excludesfile=/Users/daka/.gitignore_global
core.compression=0
difftool.sourcetree.cmd=opendiff "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
difftool.sourcetree.path=
mergetool.sourcetree.cmd=/Users/daka/Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/opendiff-w.sh "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" -ancestor "$BASE" -merge "$MERGED"
mergetool.sourcetree.trustexitcode=true
commit.template=/Users/daka/.stCommitMsg
credential.helper=osxkeychain
```

Comment: As described in [the manual](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html), use `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` to test. Only after that works move on to using Git.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add your public RSA key to bitbucket here https://bitbucket.org/account/user/username/ssh-keys/

Change `username` with your username.

**UPDATE 1:**

Git uses SSH protocol if not defined scheme, like in your post `git@bitbucket.com`. It tries to connect to bitbucket's git shell over SSH for user `git` or your `username` and get `<username>/<reponame>.git`.

For debug connection use `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v"` before `git clone` command. Try for your `username` and for `git` user. And find the difference between that connections.

Some debug messages for normal connection from `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git clone git@bitbucket.org:username/reponame.git`:

```
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:Gpy/VA4ng...
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
Enter passphrase for key '/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa': 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to bitbucket.org ([104.192.143.3]:22).
...
debug1: Entering interactive session.
...
debug1: Sending command: git-upload-pack 'username/reponame.git'
remote: Counting objects: 96, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (93/93), done.
...
```

Server accepts my connection because it knows my public SSH key.

Comment: That I have already done. Updated question.

Comment: Then it looks like you have not access rights to the repository. Check its on the appropriate page. https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/repository-access-denied/qaq-p/296376

Comment: I have the correct access rights and it works when i provide the username.

Comment: @DavidKarlsson answer updated.